# Rendering pixel-wise normals as RGB colors - artifacts

Tags: normals, normal-map, artifacts

I am dealing with the following problem. I have a fixed camera and the mesh representing a surface. I use the cloth simulator and wind source in order to generate various shapes of the mesh. For each such shape (frame) I would like to render the normal map, i.e. the per-pixel normals encoded as RGB colors. Following the wiki entry about normal mapping [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping)] I first created the texture (see Figure 1) which I apply to my mesh with the Coordinates Mapping set to "Normal", so that Blender would sample the texture according to given pixel's normal.

I set the materials Shading to be "shadeless", since I don't want any light source to alter the rendered color, i.e. the RGB color of each pixel should exactly correspond to the normal of that point on the surface to which the given pixel backprojects. When seen as a vector 
(RGB - 3D coordinates), it should always be unitary. The rendered outputs look fine, but for some shapes there appear to be strange artifacts (see Figure 2 - it comes from editor view, but the actual rendered image looks the same).

Not only these dark stripes obviously should not be there, but when I inspect their color, I can easily see that it does not correspond to a plausible unitary normal, i.e. the Blue channel value must fall within the range [0.5, 1.0] (see Figure 3).

I think the problem must relates to how Blender interpolates the normals across each face. In all the images above I used Shading = Smooth, but if I set it to be Flat the artifacts do not appear anymore (see Figure 4).

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this and how to avoid that? Or would you suggest any other way to render the image where each pixel has the colour which corresponds to the normal of the surface point it represents?

Thank you for any suggestions.

P.S.: Sorry for putting everything in one image but I do not yet have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Blender 2.77, but I also tried with 2.78c and the problem stays is the same.

Comment: Are you saving the RGB data? If so, what file format are you encoding to?

Comment: Yes, I am also saving the data, but I made the screenshots directly in the Blender in the Image editor view (before even saving them). Anyway, I am saving to TIFF with lossless compression (LZW).

Comment: Never use a display referred encoding format for data. Use EXR. Data requires float precision. That won't solve the issue, but it will solve future problems.